# Rails MediaElement js flv video not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I used MediaElement js plugin in my rails application for the video player.It is not working for FLV format video.I got an error like this **Error loading this resource**.Below see I wrote my code.How does it solve?

```
 <video width="480" height="350" controls="controls" preload="none">
      <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="<%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />

       <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="<%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />

       <!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
    <source type="video/ogg" src="<%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />

   Here I tried both format video/flv,video/x-flv but it is not working
    <source type="video/flv" src="<%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />
                     or
    <source type="video/x-flv" src="<%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />

       <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<%= Rails.root %>/app/assets/javascripts/swf/flashmediaelement.swf">
      <param name="movie" value="<%= Rails.root %>/app/assets/javascripts/swf/flashmediaelement.swf" />
      <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file= <%= @featured_video.asset.url %>" />
    </object>
 </video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 MediaElement.js video player issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843427/rails-4-mediaelement-js-video-player-issue)

Answer (score 0):

to play HTML5 videos I like to use the [videojs_rails gem](https://github.com/seanbehan/videojs_rails)

This is really easy to set up all you need to do is:

1) put the gem in your gem file

```
gem 'videojs_rails'
```

2) Add the resources to your application.js file

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require video
```

3) And that resource to application.css file

```
/*
*= require video-js
*= require_self
*/
```

4) make sure that files get loaded in the asset pipeline

```
#config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( video-js.swf vjs.eot vjs.svg vjs.ttf vjs.woff )
```

now in your view all you have to do is

```
<%= videojs_rails sources: { mp4: @featured_video.asset.ur, webm: @featured_video.asset.ur}, setup: "{}", controls: false, width:"400" %>
```

I hope that this helps.

Happy Hacking